# Redirect multiple query strings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect some urls with query strings. The url file name and query string parameter name changes but the query string value is always the same. I have created a test htaccess file that works for a single url, but I would like to have a more elegant method to change this since I have many urls in need of change.

htaccess test file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)*=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1\.html$ page1.html?query1=1 [R=301, L, NC]
```

I have a url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/page1.html?query1=0
http://www.example.com/page2.html?query2=0
http://www.example.com/page3.html?query3=0
```

and I need to change it to this:

```
http://www.example.com/page1.html?query1=1
http://www.example.com/page2.html?query2=1
http://www.example.com/page3.html?query3=1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the *regex* OR operator here.

If *query1*, *query2* etc. were just samples and are actually different strings, then use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(query1|query2|query3)=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((page1|page2|page3)\.html)$ $1?%1=1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If the parameters do have a common prefix (*query*) followed by an ordinal, then use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(query[123])=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(page[123]\.html)$ $1?%1=1 [R=301,NC,L]
```